# TeX Live - History of local changes

Tags: texlive

Is there a command line or a file that gives the history of local changes? Here are some clarifications about my needs.

1. I need the date of the last change.
2. I also need the list of packages newly installed or updated.
3. By "local" I mean the TeX Live Distribution on my computer.

I need it such as to decide to launch or not a time-consuming process, a `Python` script that tries to minimize the list of packages imported in a `TEX` or `STY` file.